# Tensor index of expression

Tags: homework-and-exercises, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, quantum-electrodynamics

When I do photon path integral quantization, I need to change variables like:
$$A^{\mu \prime}(x) \equiv A^{\mu }(x)-(\partial^2 g^{\mu \nu}-(1-\frac{1}{\xi}) \partial^{\mu}\partial^{\nu})^{-1} J_{\nu}(x). $$
In the derivation process, I came with
$$\frac{\partial^2 g_{\mu \nu}-(1-\frac{1}{\xi}) \partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}}{\partial^2 g^{\mu \nu}-(1-\frac{1}{\xi}) \partial^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}}. $$

It seems that I need to let this expression equal to $1$, but their indices are also different.

Comment: You cannot divide by a matrix. What you probably came across was an expression of the form $(M^{-1})^{\mu\nu}M_{\nu\lambda}$, for some matrix $M$, e.g. the one you wrote. This is, by definition, $\delta^\mu_{\ \lambda}$.

Comment: By $\partial^2g^{\mu\nu}$, do you mean $g^{\mu\nu}\partial^2$? Note also a second-order differential operator is only "invertible" on a suitable family of functions with a suitable constraint on solutions, e.g. an $e^{ik\cdot x}$ Ansatz.

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə Thanks, your comment is very helpful!

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for your comment! Yeah, I don't notice this "invertible" property. Since I am considering Feynman propagator of photon field, sure $\partial^2$ act on $e^{i k\cdot x}$ case. So this $invertible$ also related with differential operator?  (not just tensor) Also, P&S use $\partial^2 g^{\mu \nu}$, would this different with $g^{\mu \nu}\partial^2 $? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Daren $\partial^2 g^{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}\partial^2$ only for Minkowski space time

Comment: @KP99 Thank you very much!